# How to use my own .pb model on Jetson Nano instead of ssh-mobilenet-v2?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nvidia-jetson-nano

guys, I have a question. I'm able to run an Object Detection python example on my Jetson Nano. "ssh-mobilenet-v2" in this case. It's working fine... I also trained my own dataset & have a .pb file. How can I use it instead of "ssh-mobilenet-v2"?

```
import jetson.inference
import jetson.utils

net = jetson.inference.detectNet("ssd-mobilenet-v2", threshold=0.5)
camera = jetson.utils.gstCamera(1280, 720, "0")  # RPIcam
display = jetson.utils.glDisplay()

while display.IsOpen():
    img, width, height = camera.CaptureRGBA()
    detections = net.Detect(img, width, height)
    display.RenderOnce(img, width, height)
    display.SetTitle("Object Detection | Network {:.0f} FPS".format(net.GetNetworkFPS()))
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can refer at https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-run-tensorflow-object-detection-model-on-jetson-nano/ and https://medium.com/swlh/nvidia-jetson-nano-custom-object-detection-from-scratch-using-tensorflow-and-opencv-113fe4dba134

Answer (score 0):

A .pb file is a frozen TensorFlow graph. So you need to install TF and its depending libraries. However, you can't do so to most of the libraries including TF using `pip install` or `sudo apt install`, you need to build them from source code or from their wheels .whl file.

For a more detailed process follow Maduinos's step by step [tutorial](https://maduinos.blogspot.com/2019/08/jetson-nano-tutorialtensorflow-keras.html) in installing TensorFlow, Numpy, Scipy, Pandas, OpenCV, etc...